maximum number of members error when adding users to ACC / BIM360
I am adding one user to projects on Autodesk hubs (both BIM360 and ACC) with both these endpoints :

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/regions/eu/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id/users

and I am getting the following error :
{
"code": 1006,
"message": "You have reached the maximum number of members for BIM 360 Docs"
}
It's a bit unclear - does this mean that there are too many users on a project ? on a hub , or maybe the user is added to too many projects ?
Is there a documentation for these limits and error codes ?

The issue is well documented at https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Unable-to-add-users-to-a-BIM-360-account-that-has-BIM-360-Design-Collaboration.html?us_oa=akn-us&us_si=7f1b0201-da5b-4658-8365-1526338d172e&us_st=members%20cannot%20be%20added%20you%20have%20reached%20the%20maximum%20number
Another workaround you can try is to add members to the Project from the Project Admin module instead from Account Admin Module.
